# How does one get emacs to print a pdf properly?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, emacs, ghostscript

If you've walked the emacs road you know how amazingly powerful it can be, and how absolutely useless.

Full disclosure: my 4800 line initialization file (soon to be 3000) does manage to load 125 useful packages in 27.5 seconds, thanks to org-babel and use-package -- but I still haven't managed to coax it into printing a pdf. Oh emacs, the simplest things right?

So of course emacs experts are a shrinking population, for obvious reasons, nonetheless I'm guessing there are at least a few here who have conquered emacs, completely. Alas, I'm not yet one of you. (yet!)

My configuration, 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-04-17, compiled with ImageMagic 7 support, pdftools, aspell 6 (which I'm not using) and a host of other windows ready gems, still pushes straight postscript into my non-postscript compatible laser printer, which promptly spits out 28 pages of garbage. BLLLLpt.

Admittedly, I know little about printing under-the-hood, but I know enough to know emacs still has one foot in the last place - printing pdfs just isn't that hard to do. So here's the setup:

Ghostscript and ghostview for windows are installed, and added to path. Pdftools is working great, overriding docview when a pdf is opened. The init code is short.

```
(require 'printing)
```

For good measure:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ghostgum/gsview/gsview32.exe")
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")
```

Commands (I'd prefer to set them through pr-path-alist but, well, that's not making a lot of sense).

```
(setq pr-gs-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")
(setq pr-ps-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")

(setq lpr-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")
(setq ps-lpr-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")


(setq ps-lpr-switches '("-q" "-dNOPAUSE" "-dBATCH" "-sDEVICE=mswinpr2" "-sPAPERSIZE=a4"))

(setq pr-temp-dir "c:/emacs/.emacs.d/temp/")
```

A couple of things I've tried, the ps-print.el approach and the printing.el approach. I'd prefer to use printing.els pr-interface, as it's straightforward enough.

lpr-buffer and lpr-region

Send the print job into spooling, never to be found again. My printer is a brother laser printer, the only one on the network, shouldn't lpr be better than postscript? Well nothing happens here.

print-buffer print-region
to spooling with options, but nothing sent to the printer (despooling doesn't do anything either).

ps-print-buffer

Prints a text document! It spits out however 28 pages of junk with a pdf.

pr-ps-print-buffer

spooling, nothign happens

pr-ps-buffer-preview

Opens gsview (with an annoying registration popup) and previews the print job

pr-ps-region-using-ghostscript

28 pages of garbage.

So it seems likely I'm missing some basic piece of knowledge. Ghostscript is supposed to fill-in between postscript and non-postscript or pcl drivers, yes?

Am I missing a library? Or do I only need to configure initialization better?

Does anyone out there know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't a complete answer, but it's too long for a comment.

Ghostscript doesn't 'fill in' between drivers. The mswinpr2 device works by (abstract shorn of details) rendering the input to a bitmap, creating a DeviceContext for the printer, drawing the bitmap on the Device Context, and then telling the DC to print itself.

Basically it renders the input and then uses the Windows Print System to do the heavy lifting. So you need to be able to print to your printer from Windows, I'll assume you can already do that :-)

Have you tried using your Ghostscript command line from the Windows command shell ? Did it work ?

Ghostscript won't be 'pushing PostScript' into your printer if the input is PDF. You haven't said exactly what kind of printer you are using, beyond 'Brother', and it would be useful to know. For example is it a PCL, PostScript or 'something else' printer.

It would also be good to know what the first few bytes printed are, to see whether it's the start of a PDF file, or some other format.

I'm doubtful that you are actually launching Ghostscript, did you get a printer picker dialog ? Your command line doesn't seem to specify a printer, or the QueryUser switch to use the default printer, nor have you selected /NoCancel, so I'd expect you to see a progress dialog.

Try adding `-dQueryUser=1` to your Ghostscript command line, if you don't get a printer picker dialog, then you aren't running Ghostscript.

I'm afraid I can't offer any suggestions about why that would be though.

Comment: I noticed it was on hold, seems dumb to me, but I've disagreed with the moderators on a few occasions.

Comment: My question has been put on hold, as they've decided emacs is 'general computing hardware or software.' Not in my opinion it's not. Anything emacs is elisp, which is code. There is nothing 'general' about emacs. Anyway, I'll move this over Super User and leave it here also. Anyway, yes, I can print from windows (and from emacs, just not pdfs). The printer isn't postscript, I don't see those options on even notepad text settings. It's HL2270DW. In the cases that print, I do get a printer picker dialog. The first few lines are 1) '%PDF-1.5' 2) '%????' 3) '1 0 obj'.

Comment: OK so the PDF file is being sent directly to the printer "PDF-1.5' is a header for a PDF file. I don't know why Ghostscript isn't being called to process the PDF file ,but it looks very much like it is not. NB the options I'm referring to (NoCancel and QueryUser) are Ghostscript specific and owuld need to be added to the GS command line. But since it isn't being called there's no point...

Comment: Changing the options sent to ghostscript from emacs printing.el and ps-print.el, via the initialization file, doesn't seem to do much, though it seems to me ghostscript is being activated, only to write a ps file to a temp folder.  Here is some output from emacs messages buffer: "Send current buffer to default printer? (y or n) y
Spooling with options gswin64c.exe -dPrinted -sPageList=1 -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4..." and here from the printing-command-output: "

Comment: Here is some output from the printing command output: "c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64c.exe ("gswin32c.exe -dPrinted -sPageList=1 -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sPAPERSIZE=a4" "" "c:\\emacs\\.emacs.d\\temp\\prspool-pQOtIh.pszqoXc4")
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefinedfilename in (gswin32c.exe -dPrinted -sPageList=1 -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sPAPERSIZE=a4)"

Comment: I've set all the printing.el and ps-print.el commands to use gswin64c.exe, and the output all specifies gswin32c.exe, so it looks like emacs still isn't using the gs executable.

Comment: OK so 'undefinedfilename' is your clue here, followed by the content between the parentheses. Ghostscript thinks the input filename is the command line you've given. And indeed, looking at the 'printing command outptu', that's exactly what we see. It invokes the **64** bit version of Ghostscript (gswin64c) and passes it an argument which is the entire command line invocation of the 32-bit Ghostscript! (enclosed in prantheses). Again, I'm not an emacs user so I can't really tell you why that is happening, but it looks to me like that's your problem.

Comment: Thanks. So far I'm using a function to open the region in an external viewer and print from there. Will get back to this. The elisp is clearly sending the wrong list to the printer. Using a function to print the call stack is a good idea also (as was mentioned in another comment).

Comment: You all may be interested to know that there is an Emacs stack exchange site.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/